# Retrieving a contacts notes

Tags: android

I'm still very new to android app development, and I have hit a problem I hope u can help me with...

I am trying to retrieve any "Notes" stored against a contact within my phone. I want to check if a contact (current caller) has any notes associated to them, and then either display the contents or do some action depending on the content of them etc...

I have tried the code below as a test to see if the data is retrieved anywhere within my cursor, but although it retrieves some data, I can't see the content of a note - so I guess I'm in the wrong place!

Where I have declared contentID, this is a result of doing a lookup with the code below, and using the id that is recieved.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(inCommingNumber));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { Phone._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri , mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);


private boolean hasNote(String contactID){
    Boolean noteFound = false;

Cursor noteCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if(noteCur.moveToFirst()) { 
     int numCols = noteCur.getColumnCount();
     if(numCols > 0){
         for(int x = 0; x < numCols; x++){
             Log.d(APP_TAG, " column " + x + " contains: " + noteCur.getString(x));
         }
     }

    noteFound = true;   
} else{
    Log.d(APP_TAG, "No Note retrieved");
}

noteCur.close();
return noteFound;
}
```

Apologies, I cant seem to get the code to display properly in this post!!

Any help would be great

I have tried various things, but can't seem to be able to get this data. I have created the note by simply adding it through the normal contact manager. I'm using Android 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code would display the first note for all contacts on your phone:

```
Cursor contactsCursor = null;
try {
    contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String [] { RawContacts._ID },
            null, null, null);
    if (contactsCursor != null && contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String rawContactId = contactsCursor.getString(0);
            Cursor noteCursor = null;
            try {
                noteCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] {Data._ID, Note.NOTE},
                        Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                                new String[] {rawContactId}, null);

                if (noteCursor != null && noteCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String note = noteCursor.getString(noteCursor.getColumnIndex(Note.NOTE));
                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Note: " + note);
                }
            } finally {
                if (noteCursor != null) {
                    noteCursor.close();
                }
            }
        } while (contactsCursor.moveToNext());  
    }
} finally {
    if (contactsCursor != null) {
        contactsCursor.close();
    }
}
```

If you are storing some sort of structured data on the note to take actions on using the free form note field may not be the best approach. With the new contacts contract model you are able to attach your own data fields (in ContactsContract.Data) to a contact just give them your own unique mimetype.

Comment: Thanks, I can now get at what I need! I'm not storing anything structured, just checking for the existance of a word or phrase... I want to keep the usability as basic as possible (hence just using the standard note)... 

I have only one question on your code.. It retrieves all contacts and checks for the notes against each one. Is there a way to try and only retrieve a particulart contact given the phone number? 

I tried modifying your URI with below, but this doesnt seem to return anything!

'Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, Uri.encode(inCommingNumber));'

Comment: The RawContacts provider does not support that lookup, you will have to use the PhoneLookup table instead (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html). But bear in mind this returns a contact not a raw contact (which is what the note will be attached to). You will either need to get the specific raw contact for an account (e.g. phone, google, exchange), iterate through all raw contacts for the give contact or if you join to the data table on contactid (not rawcontactid) handle the fact that there maybe multiple notes.

Comment: Thanks, I got sorted based on your responses

Comment: How can I get the other values like phone, name etc 

String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
I'm trying to get value like this but it's not working...