# getting notes from a single contact - android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get "notes" from a single contact. It added fine but retrieving it has been a problem.

```
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + sender +"%'";
            String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE};
            Cursor c2 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
            if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
                notes = c2.getString(0);                    
            }
```

It works fine with other values like name or phone number but can't seem to get notes to retrieve correctly. It retrieves a random value like email instead.

Comment: I am not sure what can be a problem, But maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299654/retrieving-a-contacts-notes. Try to read something more about "Notes". What do you mean by "random values"? Is it always an email address?

Comment: THanks i'll take a look, if I change some things around it changes the value output but other wise it outputs email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that not all rows in the table represent contact types that have notes. You have to request the proper MIME Type.

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note is an alias for the 'data1' column that is present on all rows, so when you get a row of a different MIME Type, it represents different data.

[How to get contacts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769884/how-to-get-contacts-in-android) should give you an idea of how to do this.